# Get faces dynamically with graph api like those in fb login button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

On my site I have facebook login button that has show_faces=true.
I need to customize the faces and hide the button (only need the faces). But because everything is in iframe I cannot do that.
The login button shows faces from users that have accepted by application and are friends of the user who is logged in to fb but still have not accepted the application.

I tried to fetch the faces with fb graph api with the following:
/me/friends?fields=installed
But I get an error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user". Also instead of "me" I am trying to add the user id but I get 0.
But if the new user accepts the application this works, but this is not the case that I need.

The question is how can I get friends that use my app of the user who is logged to fb but first time on my site ?

Answer (score 1):

If the user has granted your app permission to access their information via the Auth Dialog, the call you have there, `/[USER]/friends?fields=installed` will return the user's friends list, and you can determine which of them have authorised your app via the presence, or lack of presence, of the 'installed: true' item.

If the user hasn't authorised your app, you can't get this information